# gridview row eval: column as name parameter instead of index

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview and the OnRowDataBound event is linked to this function:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    ThisRow = e.Row.DataItem as MyObjectModel;

    if (ThisRow.Property1 == null) { e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "-"; }
```

This code looks at the value of a property of the object in the data source and if it's null, converts the null to display "-" in column 5. The problem I'm having is that if I change the order of the columns of the gridview, then I need to change the index of every other modification.
What I'd like to do is change the statement "e.Row.Cells[5].Text" to something that says "the cell whose column header is xyz".

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: it is difficult because e returns current row values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be better off handling this in your gridview code rather than your code behind, especially if you are shuffling columns around.

Here's an example with ponies. Feel free to edit as needed.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Likes Ponies?">
    <ItemTemplate> 
      <asp:Label ID="uxLikesPoniesLabel" runat="server" Text=’<%#  
        DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FavoritePonies").ToString() == "" ? 
        "I like " + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FavoritePonies") + " Ponies!" :
         "-" 
        %>’ />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm using the C# `(boolean condition) ? "value if true" : "value if false"` here.

So, this code would check to see if the `FavoritePonies` column in the particular row is `""` (because NULL values are displayed as empty string) and if so, it displays "-" instead. If it's not null, then it displays what was originally in the database with `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FavoritePonies")` as "I like  Ponies!".